# RESOLVED: langflow application stucked at the thinking stage without responding

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I have successfully installed langflow (0.4.0). I test the first application "Basic Chat with Prompt and History". After inputting the openai_key at the ChatOpenAI panel, and setting "input key" as "text", I build successfully the application. However, when I open the chat interface and ask a question "hello", the application is stucked at thinking as illustrated below:

[image]

- log information

```bash
> Entering new ConversationChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from its context. If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does not know.

Current conversation:

Human: hello
AI:
/mnt/data/yangpengcheng/miniconda3/envs/langflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py:338: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncRunManager.on_retry' was never awaited
  self.before_sleep(retry_state)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
[2023-08-07 01:43:05 +0000] [88942] [INFO] ('10.12.186.19', 55850) - "WebSocket /api/v1/chat/6242294b-dad0-4698-a0cf-3766e80dd008" [accepted]
[2023-08-07 01:43:05 +0000] [88942] [INFO] connection open


> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from its context. If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does not know.

Current conversation:


Human: hello
AI:


> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from its context. If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does not know.

Current conversation:


Human: hello
AI:
[2023-08-07 01:51:10 +0000] [88940] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:88942)
[2023-08-07 01:51:10 +0000] [88940] [ERROR] Worker (pid:88942) was sent code 134!
[2023-08-07 01:51:10 +0000] [89080] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 89080
[2023-08-07 01:51:10 +0000] [89080] [INFO] Started server process [89080]
[2023-08-07 01:51:10 +0000] [89080] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2023-08-07 01:51:10 +0000] [89080] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

- I have also tested other applications, with the same problem.
- other information

  - The langflow is installed on a server. I am sure the server can connect to the internet.

#### Similar question on reddit:

- [langflow: Chat is not responding](https://www.reddit.com/r/langflow/comments/14yfs46/chat_is_not_responding/)

Could anyone help me out, thank you!

## update

This problem is caused by unavailable or blocked openai services